# Java - Passing a class as a parameter

Tags: java

I have a method that needs to create an array of objects of a certain type. Here's a part of it:

```
public void myMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
        ViewerSorter sorter = new IdeaTableSorter(i);
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

I want this method to work with all kinds of `ViewerSorter` objects, not just be coupled with `IdeaTableSorter`, but since I have to create a bunch of these objects I want to pass a reference to `myMethod` telling it which class to instantiate.

Is there a way to do this without using the Reflection API?

Comment: Sounds like you need a strategy pattern

Comment: Why not just pass in a `ViewSorter` object?

Comment: skaffman - Because I'm not just looking to pass an object, I'm looking to pass the type of class that an array of objects should be created as

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a `Factory` object that instantiates your class. This would be the [Abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). For example:

```
interface ViewSorterFactory {
   ViewSorter create();
}
class IdeaTableSorterFactory implements ViewSorterFactory {
   ViewSorter create() { return new IdeaTableSorter(); }
}
class FooTableSorterFactory implements ViewSorterFactory {
   ViewSorter create() { return new FooSorter(); }
}
```

And then:

```
myMethod(new IdeaTableSorterFactory());
```

where:

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
    ViewerSorter sorter = factory.create();
```

`Class.newInstance()` is not exactly the reflection API, though I assume you meant this option as undesirable. But give it a try - this approach is the same - you pass a factory (in this case `Class`) and call a creation method (`.newInstance()`)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using reflection. However, it would arguably be cleaner to use the Factory pattern:

```
public interface IViewerSorterFactory {
    ViewerSorter create(int i);
}

public void myMethod(IViewerSorterFactory factory) {
    for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
        ViewerSorter sorter = factory.create(i);
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in an object with a method that creates viewer sorters—a provider of sorts.

```
public void myMethod(ViewerSorterProvider creator) {
    for (int i = 0; i < something.length; i++) {
        ViewerSorter sorter = creator.create(i);
        .....
        .....
    }
}

public interface ViewerSorterProvider {
    ViewerSorter create(int i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a [factory object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) into the method that can create the appropriate types.